# MYSQL Conditions

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table `category` with a  field  `events` as varchar which its values is like this : `11,29,32`.and this values referer to `event` table ID. ( so i can say :  i have a several `event ID` from `event` table in `category` table)

So i want to select `events` from  `category` like that :

```
 SELECT *
FROM                      
event e, category c                                                    
where e.event_id in (c.events)
```

But that not give the correct result instead when i put the values manually like :

```
   SELECT *
FROM                      
event e, category c                                                    
where e.event_id in (11,29,32)
```

I hope that's clear,

Any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your problem is the way that you have set up your tables. Typically you will have an `events`, `category` and then a join table between the two.  You should not store data in a comma separated list to query against.

If you cannot alter your table structure, then you can use the MySQL function `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM event e
INNER JOIN category c                                                    
  on find_in_set(e.event_id, c.events)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d478f/2)

If you can alter your tables, then the structure should be:

```
create table events
(
  event_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  event_name varchar(50) not null
);

create table category
(
  cat_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  cat_name varchar(50) not null
);

create table events_category
(
   event_id int not null,
   category_id int not null,
   PRIMARY KEY(event_id, category_id),
   constraint fk_event 
    foreign key (event_id) references events (event_id),
   constraint fk_category 
    foreign key (category_id) references category (cat_id)
);
```

Then when you query the data you would use:

```
select *
from events e
left join events_category ec
  on e.event_id = ec.event_id
left join category c
  on ec.category_id = c.cat_id
```

Comment: I highly recommend the change in structure by storing comma separated values in a row you are eliminating a lot of the power a database can give you.

Comment: Yes i'm agree, that what i will to do , although i find this function `FIND_IN_SET ` (provided above ). Thank you very much @bluefeet

Comment: Sorry, but what is the primary key for events_category ?

Comment: @nabill. you will use both columns `event_id` and `category_id`

Comment: @nabill. see my edit with some sample scripts that you can use. :)

Comment: yes, I do not pay attention, sorry,  but it is a excellent solution, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM event e INNER JOIN category c
     ON FIND_IN_SET(e.event_id, c.events)
```

FIND_IN_SET returns 0 if `e.event_id` is not present in `c.events`, otherwise it returns its position. If the resulting value is greater than 0, the join will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to create a many-to-many relationship between categories and events. If that's the case, you really need to refactor your design to include a table that maps this relationhsip.

```
category
--------
- id
- name

event
-----
- id
- name

category_to_event
-----------------
- id
- category_id
- event_id
```

Creating this type of structure will allow you to perform the queries you seek.

Comment: There is no need to include the additional `id` field in the `category_to_event` table.  You can use the natural key of the two other fields as the PK and then have foreign key to other tables

Comment: Thanks, i will change my conception, it's great like that